# Google Map to Search in Polygon Only

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, google-places-api

I am making a Google Map (API v3) that searches within a given neighborhood. The neighborhood is not a square but a ton of different points to make a polygon bounding box. I know how to make the polygon but not sure how to get it to search only within the polygon. Below you can see I am using a radius from my center location but I don't need a radius but only a given location.

```
var request = {
  location: centerLatlng,
  radius: 800,
  types: ["school", "church", "park", "university"]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is a places API request?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

The API doesnt support passing in a artbitary polygon. If you really need to search as such, will just have to do a circle search (as in your example) - and then discard and results that are not in your shape.

Dont think there is a 'is point in side polygon' test in the Maps API itself, but can find code online
https://www.google.com/search?q=point+in+polygon